# How to count files in a folder

Tags: cmd

When I use cmd to count the files in a folder, the following set of codes give different results.  Can you show me a correct method?

```
 @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set aa=0
for %%s in ("F:\*.*") do (
        set /a aa=!aa!+1        
)
echo !aa!

set aa=0
 for %%s in ("F:\*.*") do (
     set /a aa=!aa!        
)
echo !aa!
endlocal

set aa=0
for %%s in ("F:\*.*") do (
      set /a aa=%aa%+1        
)
echo %aa%

set aa=0
for %%s in ("F:\*.*") do (
       set /a aa=%aa%       
)
echo %aa%

pause
```

Comment: Can you try re-phrasing the question? And show the differences please.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, and `fellow` refers to a Human, not a program or a thing.  The actual problem that you have is not clear either.

Comment: @foxidrive `s/fellow/following` - although it did take me a while to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two snippets will count the visible files in F:\

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set aa=0
for %%s in ("F:\*.*") do (
        set /a aa+=1        
)
echo !aa!
```

For the case above, you can also use this:

```
@echo off
set aa=0
for %%s in ("F:\*.*") do (
        set /a aa+=1        
)
echo %aa%
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much faster solution. Use DIR /B to list the files, piping the result to FIND /C to count the number of entries. The following will give the same result as the foxidrive solution.

```
@echo off
dir /b /a-d-h-s ^| find /c /v ""
```

The `/a-d-h-s` option excludes directories, hidden files, and system files. Use `/a-d` if you want to include hidden and system files.

The `/v ""` is an arcane way to cause FIND to match any value.

If you need to define a variable with the count, then use FOR /F to capture the result.

```
@echo off
for /f %%N in ('dir /b /a-d-h-s ^| find /c /v ""') do set count=%%N
echo %count%
```

Comment: On my machine this gives an error that -v is an invalid switch.

Comment: When I type `dir /b /a-d-h-s ^| find /c /v ""` into my command prompt, it returns `Invalid switch - "v".`

Comment: @Joe - The pipe symbol should only be escaped as `^|` if used within the `for` statement. If typing directly into the command prompt, then it should be `dir /b /a-d-h-s | find /c /v ""`