# Counting files in a folder in a batch file doesn't work as expected

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm having trouble when counting files in a specific folder in a batch file.
My folder at C:\logs contains seven different log files.

When I run the batch file with the following content, I'm always getting "1" as the value for `COUNT`:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET LOGS_LOCAL=C:\logs

SET COUNT=0

REM Count logs
for %%A in ("%LOGS_LOCAL%") do set /a COUNT+=1

echo !COUNT!
pause
```

As you can see I used the snippet of an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073688/how-to-count-files-in-a-folder) question but it still doesn't work. 
What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change any other settings?

Comment: You don't need delayed expansion in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented a bit and it seems that one must specify the wanted files exactly. I changed the path of my log folder from

```
SET LOGS_LOCAL=C:\Backups\weekly\logs
```

to

```
SET LOGS_LOCAL=C:\Backups\weekly\logs\*.log
```

Now, my batch file returns "7" for `COUNT`.

Comment: That's correct answer. Without `\*.log` for would match logs folders instead of contained files.

Comment: Yes.  If you actually read the help file for the `FOR` command. `(set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.`

Answer (score 3):

just to show you a different way:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d ^|find /c /v ""') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
```

`dir` parameters:
`/b` use simple format (names only, no summary, no header)
`/a-d` exclude folders (show files only)

`find /c /v ""` then just counts the entries (`/c` = count, `/v ""` = every non-empty line)

Comment: You are showing an alternative, most complex, but not addressing real issue.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ: Pete already found the solution (see time stamps), so I saw no reason to repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

You're `SET`ting `1` single directory, `C:\logs`, as your variable, `LOGS_LOCAL`, so the `COUNT` is working correctly with its output result of `1`.

What I think you intended to do count files within that directory like this:

```bat
@ECHO OFF

SET "LOGS_LOCAL=C:\logs"

SET "COUNT=0"
REM Count logs
FOR %%A IN ("%LOGS_LOCAL%\*.log") DO SET/A COUNT+=1

ECHO %COUNT%
PAUSE
```